# Best way to store date-sensitive data

Tags: mysql, database, charts, mariadb, nodes

Suppose I have a site with 10,000 members and I want to collect one particular metric from those users everyday. These metric points would be used to form points on a graph. So as you can figure, the data points are very much related to the day on which they were collected. To keep things relevant, any data older than 30 days would be deleted.

What would be the best way to store this data? I'm currently using MariaDB. I would like to have a table where the first column is for the member id, and the other columns are for each of the days where the data was collected. With each day, a new column would be created on the end of the table to store that day's data, and the first column of the table would be deleted. This seems like the most computationally efficient approach.

This would mean the titles for those columns would be the date. Similar questions have been posed on here before and people are quick to condemn the database design for having dates as column titles. I'm not necessarily disagreeing but I would like to know what a better alternative is.

The other big problem here is that trying to get MariaDB / MySQL to automatically add a column with a unique title every day and delete the first column is quite a bit more complicated than I think it ought to be. I wonder if a different database service such as PostgreSQL would be better suited for these sorts of things.

Comment: Your approach suggests that you're treating a database table like a spreadsheet. It's nothing like that at all. Create a table for your data with columns for member ID, date and whatever value you're collecting. This way your table layout is static, no columns have to be added, removed or renamed, and you can query the data quickly and easily.

Comment: One of my tables requires more than 700 time-dependent data points. Instead of having 10,000 rows, one being for each member, your approach would create more than 7 million rows. And every single date/time would be repeated 10,000 times. I don't see how that's a better approach.

Comment: Relational databases are highly optimised to handle rows, not columns. 7 million rows won't be a problem. However, if you don't think that's an appropriate approach then perhaps you should consider a different tool. Excel with Visual Basic might be what you need.